# Как добавить элемент в вектор?

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется следующий код:

```
def sigmod_func(x):
return (1/(np.exp(-x)+1))

input_vector = np.array([-1 , 2, 1]).T 
first_teta = np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=(2, 3)) 
first_hidden_layer = sigmod_func(np.dot(first_teta, input_vector))
a2_0 = np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=(1, 1))
```

Необходимо добавить к `first_hidden_layer` значение `a2_0`, таким образом, что если бы у нас имелся вектор `[1;2] и a2_0 = 0`, то результирующий вектор был бы `[0; 1; 2]`.

Пытался воспользоваться функцией `np.vstack`, но она не работает, как мне требуется.

Замечание: `first_hidden_layer` должен выйти именно вектором, а не списком, то есть массив numpy размером 3 строки и 1 столбец.

Comment: Так как вы работаете с вектор-столбцом, надо использовать `hstack`. Вместо кода в вопросе, который не имеет отношения к проблеме, лучше привести именно попытку с `vstack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input_vector = np.array([-1 , 2, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
# NOTE:                -----------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
first_teta = np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=(2, 3)) 
first_hidden_layer = sigmod_func(np.dot(first_teta, input_vector))

res = np.concatenate((a2_0, first_hidden_layer))
```

PS вместо `np.concatenate()` можно также воспользоваться `np.vstack()`

Comment: А в чем разница между .T и reshape(-1, 1)?

Comment: @OlehChaika, чтобы понять в чем разница выполните `print(input_vector.shape)` - для обоих вариантов ;)